# Symmetrized Bone Missing, Adds only Armature and Pose

Tags: modeling, rigging, edit-mode, bones, pose-mode

This is my first forray into rigging so please forgive any simple fixes I may have missed. I was attempting to mirror some bones through symmetrize, after following the proper name scheme, however it does not appear to work as it should. After the symmetrize operation, comparing the copy and the original, there is a missing "Bone" that should be under the armature in the copy. For reference I am running the 3.5.1 release, thank you in advance, any help would be appreciated.

[image: Model with nothing hidden, bones on right are original.]

[image: Scene viewer of relevant components]

The processed I used was:

1. Create and Align Bones.
2. Weight Paint individual bones to mesh.
3. Parent all to the center bone.
4. Attempt to symmetrize.

Thanks in advance for any assistance.